# ¿Cómo escribir matriz en archivo bajo una condición en C?

Tags: c

Estoy aprendiendo C y me encuentro atascado en el siguiente problema:
Debo escribir una matriz cuadrada en un archivo .txt bajo las siguientes condiciones:

1. Sólo escribir los números distintos de 0.
2. Los números en la misma fila deben estar separados por un guión y el último número no debe llevar el guión "-".

Ejemplo:

```
{1,2,0,0}
{1,1,0,0}
{1,0,0,0}
{2,3,4,5}
```

Debería Obtener:

```
1-2
1-1
1
2-3-4-5
```

Es un problema sencillo pero no logro llevarlo a código, mi idea es con un contador verificar cuantos números hay por fila y si este es mayor que 1, iterar e ir escribiendo pero en la práctica no he podido concretar mi idea. Dejo mi código que lo que hace es escribir la matriz pero con guiones que no deberían estar.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void imprimirMatriz(int (*matriz)[4]){
  FILE *fichero = fopen( "salida.txt", "w" );
  for( int fila = 0; fila < 4; ++fila ) {
    for( int col = 0; col < 4; ++col ) 
      if( matriz[fila][col]!=0 ) 
        fprintf( fichero, "%d-", matriz[fila][col] );
      fprintf( fichero, "\n" );
  }
  fclose(fichero);
}

int main(){
  int matriz1[4][4] = {
    {1,2,0,0},
    {1,1,0,0},
    {1,0,0,0},
    {2,3,4,5},
  };
  imprimirMatriz(matriz1);
  return 0; 
}
```

Esto retorna:

```
1-2-
1-1-
1-
2-3-4-5-
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez no sea la mejor solucion pero con una validacion podrias evitar los guiones extra

```
void imprimirMatriz(int (*matriz)[4]){
  FILE *fichero = fopen( "salida.txt", "w" );
  for( int fila = 0; fila < 4; ++fila ) {
    for( int col = 0; col < 4; ++col ) 
      if( matriz[fila][col]!=0 ){ 
        fprintf( fichero, "%d", matriz[fila][col] );
        if(matriz[fila][col+1]!=0 && col+1<4){
          fprintf( fichero, "-", matriz[fila][col] );
        }
      }
    fprintf( fichero, "\n" );
  }
  fclose(fichero);
}
```

Comment: Puedes ahorrarte el `if` y la segunda llamada a `fprintf` utilizando el operador ternario en el primer `fprintf` haciendo: `fprintf(fichero, "%d%c", matriz[fila][col], (col < 4 && matriz[fila][col + 1] != 0)? '-': 0);`, no es la forma más limpia, pero con cosas grandes se nota la diferencia.